# Facebook API - taggable_friends and State information

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

looked for the answer but couldn't figure it out. Can I through the Facebook API show the user all of their Facebook friends sorted by their current State they live in? It seems that of 2.0 you can't just get all friends info, but I'm wondering if through taggable_friends I can sort the friends by the State they live in.

Comment: Taggable_friends are for tagging friends. Nothing else. To get friends you use me/friends which will only give you app friends

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there any way to show a fb user their friend list sorted by state, or to tag taggable friends based on their current State? Doesn't look so from looking through the API but I'm a n00b so want to make sure.

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer CBroe.  I thought so after reading through the API, but just wanted to make sure before giving up.